Proposal: Make the work of Fama, Hansen and Schiller the new weekly topic challenge
As you probably are aware the Nobel Prize for economics has been awarded to Eugene F. Fama, Lars Peter Hansen and Robert J. Shiller whose work has had a large impact on quantitative finance. I propose to have their work as three weekly* topic challenge in their honour, starting with Fama, Hansen second and Shiller last.

+1. Not a bad idea at all!

Yep, totally agree. Well done mate.

Thanks for the support, lets seize this moment and start next Sunday. So:

Fama: 10/20/2013 - 10/26/2013
Hansen: 10/27/2013 - 11/2/2013
Shiller: 11/3/2013 - 11/9/2013.


Alright, I've created the community events. This will be promoted on the front page.
